# Draw line at top of CardView

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin app I have a `CardView` which is basically a `Frame`, and in there I have a `ListView` with `StackPanels` and `Grids` inside to style it like the image below:

[image]

I have everything in place, except the yellow line. What is the best and easiest way to add that line to a `CardView`?

Initially I was hoping to add a non-repeating Background image to it, like you can do in HTML/CSS. But that doesn't seem to be possible in a `CardView`.

Or perhaps position an `Image` element absolute and position it to the Top/Center? I'm not sure how to go about this.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'd use a BoxView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **RelativeLayout** and **BoxView** to achieve this:

For example:

```
<RelativeLayout>
   <Frame CornerRadius="20" x:Name="cardview" WidthRequest="300">
       <Label Text="$11.95"
          TextColor="Black"
          FontSize="11"
          FontAttributes="Bold"
          HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
   </Frame>
   <BoxView HeightRequest="2" BackgroundColor="Yellow"   RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=cardview, Property=Width, Factor=0.5,Constant=-50}"
            RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=cardview,Property=Height, Factor=0}"
            WidthRequest="100"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```